# How to create an a table with an id from a sequence using jooq

Tags: java, postgresql, jooq

I found out recently about the jooq package to generate sql in my java project.
I am trying to use it to create a table. This table should have a column of id with a default value taken from a sequence.

This is the sql code I am trying to implement using jooq:

```
CREATE TABLE SETTINGS(
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('seq'::regclass)
)
```

I somehow managed to generate this but it looks a bit rough

```
create.createTable("SETTINGS")
      .column("id", INTEGER.notNull().defaultValue(cast(field("nextval('seq'::regclass)") ,INTEGER)))
```

I want to know how to do it using built in functionality of jooq.

Comment: Do you *have to* use a pre-existing sequence? Why not just use an identity column, instead?

Comment: I have multiple tables that should share the same sequence.

Comment: OK,  but I don't understand the question. You already have the solution. Perhaps, replace the  `cast()` passing the `INTEGER` data type to the `field` method? What's "rough" about this?

Comment: I thought maybe there is a better way to do it. Something as like a method of default value from a sequence. A way to just specify the sequence name without explicitly writing nextval. Thanks for your help

Comment: Well, you want the `::regclass` cast, specifically? That isn't supported out of the box. But there's a `nextval` function, indeed. I'll answer, perhaps that's what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jOOQ doesn't have any equivalent for the PostgreSQL specific `::regclass` cast, but perhaps, you don't need that? I would have:

- Generated code for at least `SEQ` (though that's optional)
- Then used [`Sequence.nextval()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/dev/org.jooq/org/jooq/Sequence.html#nextval())

Like this:

```java
create.createTable("SETTINGS")
      .column("id", INTEGER.notNull().defaultValue(SEQ.nextval()))
      .execute();
```

If, for some reason, you cannot use the code generator in this case, you can construct a sequence by name using [`DSL.sequence(Name)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#sequence(org.jooq.Name))

```java
create.createTable("SETTINGS")
      .column("id", INTEGER.notNull().defaultValue(
           sequence(name("seq"), INTEGER).nextval()))
      .execute();
```

I'm not sure if that's strictly better than just using a [plain SQL template](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql-templating/) like you did, but I guess you wanted to avoid templates and use only jOOQ API?